# Google API for Google Sheets - Pull in Multiple Metrics

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I'm using an API script to pull in a single metric for Google Sheets in realtime. I can get one metrics to work, but I can't figure out how to pull in more than one and display it in the sheet.

```
// get time stamp of query run
function setTimeStamp(sheetName) {
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName)
.getRange('C2').setValue(new Date())
}

// gaGet data
function gaGet(tableId, metrics, options) {
    // Apply standard options
    options = options || {};
    options['max-results'] = options['max-results'] || '10000';
    // If errors persist up to 5 times then terminate the program.
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
          return Analytics.Data.Realtime.get(tableId, metrics, options); // 503
        } catch (err) {
          // https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors
          if (err.message.indexOf('a server error occurred') > -1) {
            Logger.log('Backend Error');
            // Note: Don't listen to Google's reply and retry request after 2 minutes
            Utilities.sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);
          } else if (err.message.indexOf('User Rate') > -1) {
            Logger.log('Rate Limit Error');
            // Exponential Backoff
            Utilities.sleep(1000 * Math.pow((i + 1), 2));
          } else if (err.message.indexOf('too many concurrent connections') > -1) {
            Logger.log('Concurrent Connections Error');
            // Exponential Backoff
            Utilities.sleep(1000 * Math.pow((i + 1), 2));
          } else {
            Logger.log(err);
            throw err;
          }
        }
    }
    throw 'Error. Max retries reached';
  }

// rt pages query
function getRtPages(){
    
    // set up the parameters  and variables
    var sheetName = 'web'; // The name of the sheet (not the Spreadsheet) we want to write the data e.g Sheet1
    var tableId = 'ga:214164114'; // The id of the view to query the data from e.g ga:123456
    //var startDate = 'yyyy-MM-dd'; // The start date of the query with the appropriate format e.g 2018-04-01 (1 April 2018)
    //var endDate = 'yyyy-MM-dd'; // The end date of the query with the appropriate format e.g 2018-04-30 (30 April 2018)
   
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
   

    // set Up the query arguments
  var metrics = ['rt:pageviews'];
  var options = {
        'dimensions': 'rt:pagePath',
        //'filters': '',
        'sort': '-rt:pageviews',
        //'segment': '',
        'samplingLevel': 'HIGHER_PRECISION',
        'max-results': '100' // To limit the results to 100. Maximum number of results: 10000

       }

  var metrics2 = ['rt:activeUsers'];
  var options2 = {
        'dimensions': 'rt:country',
        //'filters': '',
        'sort': '-rt:activeUsers',
        //'segment': '',
        'samplingLevel': 'HIGHER_PRECISION',
        'max-results': '100' // To limit the results to 100. Maximum number of results: 10000

        }


    // fetch the report
    var report = gaGet(tableId, metrics, options, metrics1, options1);
  
    // clear current sheet data  
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D101");
    range.clear();


    // fetch the report
    var report = gaGet(tableId, metrics, options);
  
    // clear current sheet data  
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D101");
    range.clear();
 
    
    // set timestamp of query run
    setTimeStamp(sheetName)
    var data = report.rows;

    
    // get the range to write and write the results
    try {
    var writeRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length) // Read reference for getRange arguments
    writeRange.setValues(data);
    }
    catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    } 

}

// test ga query to return json to log
function test(){

  var x = Analytics.Data.Realtime.get('ga:214164114', 'rt:pageviews')
  Logger.log(x)
  }
```

I've added the additional metrics variable and tried several ways try and bring them into the sheet, but I'm missing something.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you tried to combine this metrics in your code `rt:pageviews` and `rt:country` in a single request? Upon checking  [Geo - Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/geonetwork), `rt:country`  is a dimension not a metric?

Comment: I just now realized what I'm asking from doing some more reading. I'd like to be able to pull in rt:pageviews and rt:activeUsers for metrics and rt::countryand rt:pageviews for dimensions in one request. I can, or course, create multiple Google Sheets, but that seems a bit of pain to do for each new dimension and metric I might be asked to add.